# Electron is Overriding My Font

Tags: javascript, css, electron, font-face

I have a web application that my client wants to wrap in an Electron app. I 
successfully created one that loads my website correctly. However, the default font gets changed to Times New Roman rather than the Helvetica Neue shown in Chrome (specified in my boostrap-customized.css).

I have looked through the Electron documentation and found the webPreferences object that contains the defaultFontFamily object which contains a string for each of standard, serif, sansSerif, monospace, cursive, and fantasy. My problem is finding an example of how to specify the value I want in there as part of the constructor to BrowserWindow(). I have tried both

```
webPreferences.defaultFontFamily.standard: 'Helvetica'
```

and

```
webPreferences:defaultFontFamily:standard: 'Helvetica'
```

with both giving me "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" on the first period or the second colon.

I'm sure it is some simple Javascript thing that I am unfamiliar with, or at least I'm hoping it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed the problem is a simple JavaScript thing. Use `=` to set the property value instead of a `:`

Example:

```js
var obj = {
  prop1: null,
  prop2: {
    prop: 'Hi'
  }
};

//this works to set the values
obj.prop1 = 'dog';
obj.prop2.prop = 'cat';

//this doesnt work - uncomment the lines below will cause the same error you're getting
//obj.prop1: 'dog';
//obj.prop2.prop: 'cat';

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: The real culprit here turned out to be that the webPreferences object was not already defined as I thought it was. What I ended up having to do was closer to how you defined the obj in the first place, just specifying all the values there. Then passing that object to the BrowserWindow() constructor.